# How to implement contractive autoencoder in Pytorch?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, autoencoder, autograd

I'm trying to create a `contractive autoencoder` in Pytorch. I found [this thread](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/deep-contractive-autoencoder/12124) and tried according to that. This is the snippet I wrote based on the mentioned thread:

```
import datetime
import numpy as np 
import torch
import torchvision
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
from torchvision.utils import save_image, make_grid
import torch.nn as nn 
import torch.nn.functional as F 
import torch.optim as optim
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
%matplotlib inline

dataset_train = datasets.MNIST(root='MNIST',
                               train=True,
                               transform = transforms.ToTensor(),
                               download=True)
dataset_test  = datasets.MNIST(root='MNIST', 
                               train=False, 
                               transform = transforms.ToTensor(),
                               download=True)
batch_size = 128
num_workers = 2
dataloader_train = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset_train,
                                               batch_size = batch_size,
                                               shuffle=True,
                                               num_workers = num_workers, 
                                               pin_memory=True)

dataloader_test = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset_test,
                                               batch_size = batch_size,
                                               num_workers = num_workers,
                                               pin_memory=True)

def view_images(imgs, labels, rows = 4, cols =11):
    imgs = imgs.detach().cpu().numpy().transpose(0,2,3,1)
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))
    for i in range(imgs.shape[0]):
        ax = fig.add_subplot(rows, cols, i+1, xticks=[], yticks=[])
        ax.imshow(imgs[i].squeeze(), cmap='Greys_r')
        ax.set_title(labels[i].item())


# now let's view some 
imgs, labels = next(iter(dataloader_train))
view_images(imgs, labels,13,10)

class Contractive_AutoEncoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.encoder = nn.Linear(784, 512)
        self.decoder = nn.Linear(512, 784)

    def forward(self, input):
        # flatten the input
        shape = input.shape
        input = input.view(input.size(0), -1)
        output_e = F.relu(self.encoder(input))
        output = F.sigmoid(self.decoder(output_e))
        output = output.view(*shape)
        return output_e, output

def loss_function(output_e, outputs, imgs, device):
    output_e.backward(torch.ones(output_e.size()).to(device), retain_graph=True)
    criterion = nn.MSELoss()
    assert outputs.shape == imgs.shape ,f'outputs.shape : {outputs.shape} != imgs.shape : {imgs.shape}'
    
    imgs.grad.requires_grad = True 
    loss1 = criterion(outputs, imgs)
    print(imgs.grad)
    loss2 = torch.mean(pow(imgs.grad,2))
    loss = loss1 + loss2 
    return loss 

epochs = 50 
interval = 2000
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
model = Contractive_AutoEncoder().to(device)
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr =0.001)

for e in range(epochs):
    for i, (imgs, labels) in enumerate(dataloader_train):
        imgs = imgs.to(device)
        labels = labels.to(device)

        outputs_e, outputs = model(imgs)
        loss = loss_function(outputs_e, outputs, imgs,device)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        if i%interval: 
            print('')

    print(f'epoch/epoechs: {e}/{epochs} loss : {loss.item():.4f} ')
```

For the sake of brevity I just used one layer for the encoder and the decoder. It should work regardless of number of layers in either of them obviously!

But the catch here is, aside from the fact that I don't know if this is the correct way of doing this, (calculating gradients with respect to the input), I get an error which makes the former solution wrong/not applicable.

That is:

`imgs.grad.requires_grad = True`

produces the error :

> **AttributeError** : 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'requires_grad'

I also tried the second method suggested in that thread which is as follows:

```
class Contractive_Encoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.encoder = nn.Linear(784, 512)
        
    def forward(self, input):
        # flatten the input
        input = input.view(input.size(0), -1)
        output_e = F.relu(self.encoder(input))
        return output_e

class Contractive_Decoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.decoder = nn.Linear(512, 784)

    def forward(self, input):
        # flatten the input
        output = F.sigmoid(self.decoder(input))
        output = output.view(-1,1,28,28)
        return output


epochs = 50 
interval = 2000
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

model_enc = Contractive_Encoder().to(device)
model_dec = Contractive_Decoder().to(device)

optimizer = optim.Adam([{"params":model_enc.parameters()},
                        {"params":model_dec.parameters()}], lr =0.001)

optimizer_cond = optim.Adam(model_enc.parameters(), lr = 0.001)

criterion = nn.MSELoss()

for e in range(epochs):
    for i, (imgs, labels) in enumerate(dataloader_train):
        imgs = imgs.to(device)
        labels = labels.to(device)

        outputs_e = model_enc(imgs)
        outputs = model_dec(outputs_e)
        loss_rec = criterion(outputs, imgs)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss_rec.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        imgs.requires_grad_(True)
        y = model_enc(imgs)
        optimizer_cond.zero_grad()
        y.backward(torch.ones(imgs.view(-1,28*28).size()))

        imgs.grad.requires_grad = True
        loss = torch.mean([pow(imgs.grad,2)])
        optimizer_cond.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer_cond.step()
        
        if i%interval: 
            print('')

    print(f'epoch/epoechs: {e}/{epochs} loss : {loss.item():.4f} ')
```

but I face the error :

```
RuntimeError: invalid gradient at index 0 - got [128, 784] but expected shape compatible with [128, 512]
```

How should I go about this in Pytorch?

Comment: First of all, check if your data is being loaded correctly (use maybe `image, label = next(iter(train_loader))` and then check the `image` using matplotlib). Another thing is that you convert `imgs` to `cuda`, but I think you need to cast it to a PyTorch tensor first. So, you should do that using `imgs = torch.autograd.Variable(imgs)` and then you can do `.to(device)`.

Comment: Everything is correct regarding the loading, etc. imgs and labels are tensors by default. since in the dataset, they are converted into tensors using ToTensor() transformations. Tensors were merged with Variable starting from 0.4 (that is they can have gradients and be traced) and Variable is deprecated for quite some time now. torch.Tensor is used for pretty much everything!

Comment: Try printing out `imgs.grad` or it's shape and check if it has something in it. If you want to sort of take a double backward pass (which is why you are setting the `requires_grad` parameter of the gradients of `imgs`), then first check if `imgs.grad` is a Tensor with some values in it (and not `NoneType` as mentioned in the error).

Comment: The issue is, it stays NoneType and I cant seem to find a way to make it work. that is the gist of my question here! I added the google colab link which you can use to run the code if you like.

Comment: I think I understand the problem, though I don't know how to solve it since I am not familiar with this kind of network. The problem is that `imgs.grad` will remain `NoneType` until you call `backward` on something that has `imgs` in the computation graph. Now, you do call backward on `output_e` but that does not work properly. I think you should ask this on the PyTorch forums.

Comment: Why don't you use `backward` on the MSELoss term (between autoencoder reconstruction and input). That should give the gradients.

Comment: Thanks, where exactly do you mean to use backward? which method are you referring to?

Comment: Do you mean sth like this : 
```def loss_function(output_e, outputs, imgs, device):
    ...   
    
    imgs.requires_grad = True    
    loss1 = criterion(outputs, imgs)   
    loss1.backward(retain_graph=True)   

    loss2 = torch.mean(pow(imgs.grad,2))   
    imgs.requires_grad = False    
    imgs.grad.data.zero_()   
    loss = loss1 + loss2    
    return loss ```

Comment: Yes, something like that. Did it work?

Comment: Yup! it worked in a sense I have no more any errors, and the loss decreases, but I want to be sure everything we have thus far written is right! Can you verify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Summary**

The final implementation for contractive loss that I wrote is as follows:

```
def loss_function(output_e, outputs, imgs, lamda = 1e-4, device=torch.device('cuda')):

    criterion = nn.MSELoss()
    assert outputs.shape == imgs.shape ,f'outputs.shape : {outputs.shape} != imgs.shape : {imgs.shape}'
    loss1 = criterion(outputs, imgs)

    output_e.backward(torch.ones(outputs_e.size()).to(device), retain_graph=True)    
    # Frobenious norm, the square root of sum of all elements (square value)
    # in a jacobian matrix 
    loss2 = torch.sqrt(torch.sum(torch.pow(imgs.grad,2)))
    imgs.grad.data.zero_()
    loss = loss1 + (lamda*loss2) 
    return loss
```

and inside training loop you need to do:

```
for e in range(epochs):
    for i, (imgs, labels) in enumerate(dataloader_train):
        imgs = imgs.to(device)
        labels = labels.to(device)

        imgs.retain_grad()
        imgs.requires_grad_(True)

        outputs_e, outputs = model(imgs)
        loss = loss_function(outputs_e, outputs, imgs, lam,device)

        imgs.requires_grad_(False)

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
    print(f'epoch/epochs: {e}/{epochs} loss: {loss.item():.4f}')
```

**Full explanation**

As it turns out and rightfully @akshayk07 pointed out in the comments, the implementation found in Pytorch forum was wrong in multiple places. The notable thing, being it wasn't implementing the actual contractive loss that was introduced in [Contractive Auto-Encoders:Explicit Invariance During Feature Extraction](http://www.icml-2011.org/papers/455_icmlpaper.pdf) paper! and also aside from that, the implementation wouldn't work at all for obvious reasons that will be explained in a moment.

The changes are obvious so I try to explain what's going on here. First of all note that `imgs` is not a **leaf node**, so the gradients would not be retained in the image `.grad` attribute.

In order to retain gradients for non leaf nodes, you should use `retain_graph()`. `grad` is only populated for leaf Tensors. Also `imgs.retain_grad()` should be called before doing `forward()` as it will       instruct the `autograd` to store grads into non-leaf nodes.

**Update**

Thanks to @Michael for pointing out that the correct calculation of Frobenius Norm is actually (from [ScienceDirect](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/frobenius-norm)):

> the square root of the sum of the **squares** of all the matrix entries

and **not**

> the the square root of the sum of the **absolute values** of all the
>   matrix entries as explained [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrobeniusNorm.html)

Comment: Earlier, I was just commenting based on your code and your question, but it would be better if you refer to the original paper and also check with other open source implementations like [this](https://github.com/avijit9/Contractive_Autoencoder_in_Pytorch/blob/master/CAE_pytorch.py). Just to be sure you are replicating the paper correctly, because this thing might still work even if you don't exactly follow the original paper.

Comment: You are right! but what we did should work as we are basically doing the same thing yet differently, instead of building the whole jacobian matrix, we are simply using the autograd to dervie the gradients with respect to the input. concerning checking against other example, what exactly should I be checking, the gradients or the output or loss?

Comment: by the way, in a similar config, the two losses using the link you provided vs what we have here ) is as follows:loss2 uses ```lam= 1e-10``` 
```loss: 0.2316920906305313 loss2: 0.2316921353340149
loss: 0.22340171039104462 loss2: 0.2234017252922058
loss: 0.21272771060466766 loss2: 0.21272774040699005
loss: 0.19688208401203156 loss2: 0.19688212871551514
loss: 0.17924705147743225 loss2: 0.17924711108207703
loss: 0.1550494283437729 loss2: 0.15504947304725647
loss: 0.1335817575454712 loss2: 0.13358180224895477
loss: 0.11488725244998932 loss2: 0.1148873120546341
```so I say this is correct

Comment: Better to check the maths by writing out the equations in your approach and in the link I gave. But if you've done that already and they match, then it's correct.

Comment: You are actually right! I have to get the outputs_e to backward, for some reason that doesnt work while it should! and I shouldnt be needing to backprop from loss1! however, its really strange the loss is the same for both methods!

Comment: ’’’output_e.backward(torch.ones(outputs_e.size()).to(device), retain_graph=True)’’’

For this line, is the ones tensor specifying some upstream gradient (lets say dLoss/d(output_e))?. Except in this case, you are setting it to a ones tensor, so that it doesn’t effect the backprop computation at all for the computational graph from output_e to the input. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

In PyTorch 1.5.0, a high level `torch.autograd.functional.jacobian` API is added. This should make the contractive objective easier to implement for an arbitrary encoder. For `torch>=v1.5.0`, the contractive loss would look like this:

```py
contractive_loss = torch.norm(torch.autograd.functional.jacobian(self.encoder, imgs, create_graph=True))
```

The `create_graph` argument makes the jacobian differentiable.